# How to change "always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, file-types

I have a `qml.qrc` file that accidentally I went for opening it the `Notepad` program. The sign of a `Notepad` set on the middle part of the shape of the file. Now when I run my program using `Qt Creator` I get an error.

I used `regedit` and deleted the **a** value and rebooted Windows 7 but when I double clicked on the file, it again will opened and that value **a** is returned to the `regedit`.
How to solve the issue please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right click on the file that has the wrong association and click on the option open with at the bottom of the menu. Then choose the right program and click the option always open with.

Comment: The file initially was an unknown file.